# Numpy call array values by list of indices

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 2D array of values, and I want to call it by two list of indices x,y. It used to work perfect before, I don't know why it's not working now, maybe python version, not sure.

```
x = np.squeeze(np.where(data['info'][:,2]==cdp)[0])
y = np.squeeze(np.where((data['Time']>=ub) & (data['Time']<=lb))[0])

s = data['gather'][x,y]
```

Error:

```
IndexError: shape mismatch: indexing arrays could not be broadcast together with shapes (36,) (45,)
```

I don't what is the problem. It works when I do it in two stages.

```
s = data['gather'][:,y]; s = s[x,:]
```

But, I can't do this, I need to do at one run

Comment: Can you simply try `data['gather'][:,y][x,:]` ?

Comment: You can't index an array with 2 arrays that don't broadcast together.  Reread the `advanced indexing`  section  of the docs.  You never could.

Comment: MATLAB and numpy are different in how they handle indexing of blocks.  `x[[0,1,2], [0,1,2]]` selects a diagonal, not a (3,3) block.

Comment: @NikP 's way should be correct.

Comment: What's `data`?  Dictionary?  dataframe?

Comment: @Nick P, works well. Thanks Nick

Answer (score 1):

```
In [92]: data = np.arange(12).reshape(3,4)                                                                           
In [93]: x,y = np.arange(3), np.arange(4)                                                                            
In [94]: data[x,y]                                                                                                   
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-94-8bd18da6c0ef> in <module>
----> 1 data[x,y]

IndexError: shape mismatch: indexing arrays could not be broadcast together with shapes (3,) (4,)
```

When you provide 2 or more arrays as indices, `numpy` broadcasts them against each other.  Understanding `broadcasting` is important.

In MATLAB providing two indexing arrays (actually 2d matrices) fetches a block.  In numpy, to arrays, if they match in shape, fetch elements, e.g. a diagonal:

```
In [99]: data[x,x]                                                                                                   
Out[99]: array([ 0,  5, 10])
```

The MATLAB equivalent requires an extra function, 'indices to sub' or some such name.

Two stage indexing:

```
In [95]: data[:,y][x,:]                                                                                              
Out[95]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11]])
```

`ix_` is a handy tool for constructing indices for block access:

```
In [96]: data[np.ix_(x,y)]                                                                                           
Out[96]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11]])
```

Notice what it produces:

```
In [97]: np.ix_(x,y)                                                                                                 
Out[97]: 
(array([[0],
        [1],
        [2]]), array([[0, 1, 2, 3]]))
```

that's the same as doing:

```
In [98]: data[x[:,None], y]                                                                                          
Out[98]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11]])
```

`x[:,None]` is (3,1), `y` is (4,); they broadcast to produce a (3,4) selection.